# Subclassing a subclass of UIViewController load issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, subclassing

So, here's the issue. I'm relatively new to iOS programming, and I've taken on a giant project.

I'm working on a game with multiple levels which basically follow the same pattern, but have different sprite images and values, and I just decided to lay out all the levels in IB for speed's sake (not necessarily best practices, I know, but work with me). Each "level" has its own view controller, along the lines of "FireLevel1ViewController," "FireLevel2ViewController," etc. All of these view controllers inherit from a custom subclass of UIViewController I created called "GameController."

My problem is, when I open each level on my test device, GameController's viewDidLoad is getting called before the init or viewDidLoad methods of my subclass controllers, and so none of my level images/values are getting assigned to the superclass properties. Specifically, I have a pause menu that ought to be hidden at the outset of the level (I am doing setHidden in GameController's viewDidLoad), but since GameController's viewDidLoad runs before FireLevel1 has a chance to associate the correct IB property with PauseMenu, GameController just hides an empty view, and the actual PauseMenu never gets hidden.

I may have multiple problems going on here, but mostly I think I'm not really understanding correctly how to subclass a subclass of UIViewController and how to get the second subclass's properties/values/images to work in the first subclass's methods.

Thanks so much for any help! I hope that question made sense...

Code for GameController:

```
@implementation GameController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:pauseMenu];
    [pauseMenu addSubview:helpMenu];

    //Hides the pause and help menus until their respective buttons are pressed
    [pauseMenu setHidden:YES];
    [helpMenu setHidden:YES];
    isPaused = NO;
}
```

Code for FireLevel1Controller:

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if(self)
    {
           theMainview = mainview;
           theScene = scene;
           theBG = bg;
           theHudView = hud;
           thePauseView = pauseMenu;
           theHelpView = helpMenu;
    }

return self;
}


-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    firstTurret = [[StationaryEnemy alloc]init:turretImage1 baseView:base1];
    secondTurret = [[StationaryEnemy alloc]init:turretImage2 baseView:base2];

    NSLog(@"I'm in view did load");

}
```

Comment: GameController's `viewDidLoad:` shouldn't be called before the subclass initialization unless there's something odd going on in the GameController initialization.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  To help you debug your problem, we need more information.  Put a breakpoint in `-[GameController viewDidLoad]`.  Run your app and, when it hits the breakpoint, copy the stack trace.  Edit your post and paste in the stack trace.

Comment: Ok, after having added breakpoints at both the FireController's viewDidLoad and GameController's viewDidLoad, it's calling those in the correct order, and the problem seems to be that it's never calling FireController's init (I added several breakpoints there, and it never stopped at any of them), so I think I'm probably doing something wrong there...

Comment: Ahhhh I figured it out - I was accidentally negating my variables. I should've been doing mainview = theMainview; instead of theMainview = mainview - I was just assigning them all to zero. I also moved them all out of init into viewDidLoad, and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `viewWillAppear`? That method should be called after all the visible UI elements have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh I figured it out - I was accidentally negating my variables. I should've been doing mainview = theMainview; instead of theMainview = mainview - I was just assigning them all to zero. I also moved them all out of init into viewDidLoad, and moved [super viewDidLoad] underneath them, and now it works perfectly!